# Visual studio 2013 works slow after Update 4

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Does anybody know if Visual Studio Update 4 bring something which can consume CPU too much? 
I had update 3 before and did not have any issues with performance, but after Update 4 I noticed that Visual studio is doing something (even if it's in background) and CPU is not going lower that 15%
Also it's not very responsive after 1-2 hours or work, I have to restart it.

I noticed than it's IsAssertEtwEnabled takes most of CPU, but have no idea what is it, I googled but found only one answer about DevExpress plugin, but I don't have it.
(if I uninstall updates, everything back to normal, but I prefer to have software to be updated)

**UPDATE:** I found the issue, it's browser link causing CPU and performance problems. After disabling browser link it get back to normal.
See second screenshot to see how to disable browser link

[image]

[image]

Comment: Comfirmed, was wondering if it was just me. http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ft4IL.png Probably a good time to hope over to visualstudio uservoice. And actually, I'm running update 3, but the only change was loading VS2015 preview.

Comment: With Google Chrome VS2013 is spamming browser linkdon't know why.

Answer (score 5):

Try disabling browser link.  Thats what I did.

Answer (score 0):

It happens with Visual Studio.
The best part is to remove it completely and re install everything from first. 
This is mainly caused because you have did Update 
That IS:
**1) Remove your Visual Studio and Emulator's and updates completely.
2)Install Visual studio.
3)now install just the current version update 3
4)now the emulators.**
Your done!!!

Answer (score 0):

It happens with Visual Studio because you have updated that not installed the latest version directly, when you are upgrading that some threads are running behind that checks the current version every time you are connected to internet

1. Try reinstalling that visual studio
2. Diable browser link

Answer (score 0):

I'd also recommend to uninstall Visual Studio completely and install the latest version VS 2013 with Update 4. It's the current stable version.

And works better on my PC as compared to VS 2012. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if disabling browser link does not solve the problem, try to run VS in safe mode by running `devenv.exe /safemode`. This will disable any third party add-ins and you can check if some add-ins have issues with the new update.

If it still doesn't solve the problem, try reinstalling VS, and make sure that the installation run without any problems.