# Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate very very slow for sitecore development

Tags: performance, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tds

My laptop has an i5 processor and 8 GB RAM and i5.

I've also installed Resharper. When doing a sitecore development development the Visual studio sometimes hangs and build/deployment process is extremely slow. We use TDS 5.0.0.4. It's a multisite solution with MVC.

I tried solutions on link below:

- [Visual studio 2013 works slow after Update 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27131761/visual-studio-2013-works-slow-after-update-4)
- [Why is VS 2013 very slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617670/why-vs-2013-is-very-slow)

But none of above solved my issue. Other team members are facing same issue.

Comment: Can you post an screenshot of your solution explorer>

Comment: What kind of drive is the solution stored on? SSD, HDD? If HDD, how fast (10k, 7.2k, 5.4k,  slower)? From your build logs, what steps are taking the most time? How many sitecore items do your TDS solutions hold? Does it happen on non-sitecore projects?

Comment: Drive is SSD. According to build log the unit test are taking most of the time (note unit test are mocked). In terms of TDS solution, it's multi site i.e. 4 site so far. We don't story any images in TDS only configuration items, layouts and renderings.

Comment: Read this and get better hardware http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2015/05/sitecore-xp-development-hardware-recommendations.aspx